# How setting proxies for client in application.yml works with Micronaut?

Tags: micronaut

I'm using Micronaut 1.1.4 and at our company we're trying to adopt it. But handling proxy with Micronaut seems to be a headache.

We have tried the low level client describe in the simple example "Bintray" [link](https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-http-client/guide/index.html). It's work without any problem when no proxy are involved.

But if we are behind some kind of proxy this example failed : read timeout. We tried the solution proposed [here](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/1611), but it doesnt work.

how proxies setted into application.yml are supposed to work in Micronaut? how to set proxies for client (declarative or low level) by the way because it seems to be something mysterious?

**Edit 1**:

While testing i'm came across these facts:

**application.yml :**

```
---
micronaut:
  application:
    name: myapp
---
micronaut:
  http:
    client:
      proxy-address: proxy:port
      proxy-type: HTTP
```

This one only work in test classes for @inject custom client and not for rxhttpclient.

**MyTest.java**

```
@Inject @Client("/test") RxHttpClient localhostClient; // call through this client will failed because of how the proxy is set
@Inject CustomClient myClient; // call will succeed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Micronaut 1.2 and above solve the problems.